# SSRS Report Builder Center Data Bar Data Label in Column instead of on the bar

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating an SSRS report in SSRS report builder 3.0.  I currently have a table where the rows have a Data Bar inside of the cells.  I cant figure out how to get the data label to center on the row.  I tried selecting center under the Data Bar "Custom Attributes for "bar label style" and also under the Data Label under "position".  Both seem to just center the label on the Data Bar itself not on the row.

I'm under the reputation limit or i would post an image of what I'm talking about.

Image link of current configuration https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO1vC.jpg

Comment: You can still post a link to an image - that might help.  What you're describing sounds like it's "working as intended", but I may be misunderstanding the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realise that this is an old post, but I stumbled across this forum searching for an answer to the same question.  Unfortunately, I have to agree with Christopher, in that there is no way around the issue (that I know of).

However, I have used a very simple workaround that displays the data bar and values neatly, and thought it may be useful for others.

Quite simply, I have added another column to the right of the data bar, and have entered the same field.  I have then removed the borders between the two textboxes, so that it displays the data bar to the left with the values aligned to the right.

While this does not provide an answer to the question as such, I hope that it may help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: This is a great idea and it works on my case. I don't know how I didn't think of it before!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, unfortunately, that what you seek is not possible. The reason being that the label is a part of the bar. The label is defined for the entire series, and for each label, it is positioned relative to the bar itself. Relative to either the start or the end or the middle of the bar, but not relative to the chart's container.

What I imagine you wanting is to define something that is centered in the cell itself, which would have to be a direct component of the cell (e.g., placeholder, entered text). Unfortunately, when using a databar, you cannot add anything else into that cell.